# private home proxy server

Tags: php

How do I make a proxy site for a home URL (EX: 192.168.1.190) to bypass the web filter we have set?  Don't worry, I am in cahoots with the person that monitors this stuff, so this is for that person.

Thanks!

Comment: My advice wouldn't be to use PHP for this. I would use a dedicated cache like Squid with SSH tunnelling (having been in this situation), which is fairly trivial to set up under Linux.

Comment: Im doing this under a Mac platform and Windoze XP platform.

Answer (score 1):

a simple way is to setup an PHP Proxy script:

My Favourite is : [phpMyProxy](http://www.phpmyproxy.com/)

But take care, the script is very resource intensive.

Comment: I want to make one for my priveate home URL so that it doesn't block it because it is a proxy server.

Thanks!

Ben